# PHP-Почему не работает форма авторизации, вообще не видит переменные

Tags: php, html, база-данных

PHP:

```
<?php
    include "components/header.php";
    include "components/connect.php";

    if($_POST){
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        print_r($login);
        $users = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` 
            WHERE `login` = '{$_POST['login']}' AND `password` = '{$_POST['password']}'");
        if($users->num_rows != 1){
            $_SESSION['errors']['login'] = "Неверный логин или пароль";
        }

        if(!isset($_SESSION['errors'])){
            $user = $users->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['user']['id'] = $value['id'];
            $_SESSION['user']['isAdmin'] = $value['isAdmin'];
            header("Location: zayav.php");
            
        } 
        
        header("Location: index.php ");

    }

?>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Логин">
        <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
        <button>Войти</button>
        <?php if(isset($errors)) {echo "<p>$errors</p>";} ?>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: почему PHP и HTML написаны раздельно? **Почему нельзя привести содержимое файла целиком**? Почему мы должны сами придумать, как эти два куска кода относятся друг к другу?

Comment: ...Соедини визуально два кода, они идут в таком порядке

Comment: Зачем в action стоит /?

Comment: Откуда берется переменная $errors ? Почитайте про SQL injection , ибо у вас сейчас не авторизация, а дыра. Ваш код после отправки формы делает безусловную переадресацию на index.php, после которой данных в $_POST не может быть в принципе.